# before_create callback breaking transaction

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

If I assign booleans in my callbacks, does it affect transactions? I suspect the assignment of false also return self.assigned in case below and thus breaks my transaction. Is this the case?

```
before_create :set_default_values

def set_default_values
  self.finished = false
  self.assigned = false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this does affect the transactions. Here's the description from the official Rails doc:

> If a before_* callback returns false, all the later callbacks and the
>   associated action are cancelled. If an after_* callback returns false,
>   all the later callbacks are cancelled. Callbacks are generally run in
>   the order they are defined, with the exception of callbacks defined as
>   methods on the model, which are called last.

I would just set these to `:default => false` in your migration file for setting up this table or columns. This definitely be easier.

Here's the callbacks doc:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: This is right on. You can return true from the callback if you can't set defaults for legacy reasons or whatnot.

Comment: Exactly. I always forget about legacy databases (-_-)